# Complete residue systems of $k$th powers reducing "in order".

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I already know about complete residue systems and things like that, but solving a basic number theory problem I came across this:

Checking $x^{3} \pmod 6$ for $x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5 \pmod 6$, we get that $0^{3} \equiv 0, 1^{3} \equiv 1, 2^{3} \equiv 2, 3^{3} \equiv 3, 4^{3} \equiv 4, 5^{3}\equiv 5$.

Are there theorems about when these elements reduce "in order" (i.e. $a^k \equiv a \pmod n$ for all $a$)  perhaps pertaining to the $k$th power and modulus?

Could think of this as like a set where all elements satisfy a weak version of fermat's little theorem. Although we could restrict this further if we wanted to.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_(ring_theory) Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n And I guess this is also related, although it's not restricted to modular arithmetic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

Comment: Ah, so one could say a better generalization is something like a modulus where every element is $k$-idempotent. Although I am also interested in the generalization for the basic number theory case as well, if there is one.

Comment: In particular, we have $a^{k-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ when $\gcd(a,n) = 1$. Thus $k = m\cdot \lambda(n) + 1$ where $\lambda$ is the Carmichael function. When $n$ is squarefree, this is a sufficient condition (i.e. for squarefree $n$ we have $a^{m\lambda(n) + 1} \equiv a \pmod{n}$ for all $a$). For $n$ not squarefree, there's only $k  = 1$: Let $p^2 \mid n$, then $p^k \not\equiv p \pmod{p^2}$ for all $k \geqslant 2$.

Comment: This is an active field of research because it's closely related to the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), which is the basis of some cryptography systems. That is, for large prime $p$ solving $a^x\equiv b \pmod p$ is computationally intensive.